# Google maps info window not opening

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am trying to use the info window with google maps pins however when i click on a pin to open the info window nothing happens, i don't receive any errors in the console but the function is being fired as there should be a log when it runs.

I get the data from a local json file that i am trying to use to populate the list.

I have read through event closures but i am unsure if this is my problem here.

```
    function test(markers){

      var gmarkers = [];
    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(markers.map[0].lat, markers.map[0].lng),
        zoom: 2,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var latlngbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
    var i = 0;
    var interval = setInterval(function () {
        var data = markers[i];
        var category = markers.map[i].category;
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(markers.map[i].lat, markers.map[i].lng);
        var icon = "";
        switch (markers.map[i].type) {
            case "techstation":
            icon = "red";
            break;
            case "event":
            icon = "blue";
            break;
            case "virtual":
            icon = "yellow";
            break;
            default:
            icon = "red";
        }

        icon = "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/" + icon + ".png";
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatlng,
            map: map,
            category: category,
            title: markers.map.title,
            icon: new google.maps.MarkerImage(icon)
        });
        gmarkers.push(marker);

        for (var z = 0; z < markers.map.length; z++) {
        var marker1 = markers.map[z];
        console.log(marker1.description);
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, 'click', function () {
          console.log("mouseover");
        infowindow.setContent(marker1.description);
        infowindow.open(map, marker1);
        });
        }

        latlngbounds.extend(marker.position);
        i++;
        if (i == markers.map.length) {
            clearInterval(interval);
            var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
            map.setCenter(latlngbounds.getCenter());
            map.fitBounds(latlngbounds);
        }
      }, 80);
```

Comment: it might just be what you posted here bu you are missing the final `}`

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue, including sample data.

Answer (score 0):

There is typo in your code.

You declare infowindow

```
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(); // notice capital "W"
```

and you using

```
// notice lowercase "w"
infowindow.setContent(marker1.description);
infowindow.open(map, marker1);
```

Comment: I have changed the typo and it hasn't changed anything, the info window still isn't displayed.

Comment: Unfortunately i haven't for some reason it still won't open the info window, however if i declare the info content outside of the event listener if will open the window but sometimes it will show the last item from the array or it will show an empty box

Comment: check the content you assigning is a string.

Comment: `marker.addListener('click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  });`  try this syntax, and give us your html and js. or create a fiddle and give us link

Answer (score 0):

try changing the portion of code that listens for marker clicks to:

```
for( var z = 0; z < markers.map.length; z++ ) {
    var mkr = markers.map[z];
    console.log( mkr.description );

    google.maps.event.addListener( mkr, 'click', function( event ) {
        console.log("click event triggered on marker: open infowindow");

        infoWindow.setContent( this.description );
        infoWindow.open( map, this );
        infoWindow.setPosition( this.position );/* need to set the position */
    }.bind( mkr ));/* for convenience, bind to the marker `mkr` so you can use `this` - personal preference i guess */
}
```

Comment: I have tried this solution however it doesn't work, the info window still isn't displayed, could it be because of the data from the array? or should it still display something?